# Force system QT libraries to use openssl libraries shipped with the application

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, qt5, qt5.7

My application = libssl.so (`1.0.2f`) + libcrypto.so (`1.0.2f`) + `my_app_exe`

On Debian 9, QT version is `5.7` and openssl is `1.0.2l`

`my_app_exe` returns `1.0.2l` for `QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()`, which means its using system openssl version.

Can I force QT libraries to somehow use openssl shipped along with my application?

I've tried setting library path using `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(const QString &path)`, but QT library still picks up system openssl version.

### Constraints:

- Can't recompile QT library thats present on the system
- Can't ship QT library along with the application
- Can't change RPATH on system QT libraries

`my_app_exe` already uses `RPATH` which points to the current directory where shipped openssl resides.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367025/how-to-force-using-local-shared-libraries-over-system-libraries

Comment: What if: `QString sysLibPath = qgetenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
qputenv(myLibPath + ":" + sysLibPath);` in `main()` before `QApplication` constructed? In case if the above solution won't satisfy somehow.

Comment: @AlexanderVX tried that and I'm not able to get it to work, it still loads from old location

Comment: That seems like Qt library referring to SSL libs at some prebuilt path. It is actually possible to configure Qt for building with SSL.

Comment: I can't change QT on user's system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian 9 I was able to get the correct SSL and Crypto libraries to load if I preload (load them as the first thing in the main()) using `QLibrary` calls. This is exactly what QT libraries are doing [loadOpenSsl()](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp#L418)

```
    int main()
    {
        QLibrary libcrypto, libssl;
        libcrypto.setFileNameAndVersion(QLatin1String("crypto"), QLatin1String(SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER));    
        libssl.setFileNameAndVersion(QLatin1String("ssl"), QLatin1String(SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER));

        ...<snipped>...
        return 0;
     }
```

Remember, I also have RPATH set on the application

```
$ objdump -x my_app_exe | grep -i RPATH
  RPATH                $ORIGIN/lib
```

crypto libraries are stored in `./my_app_exe/lib/lib{ssl,crypto}.so`

BTW, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't work for me.