# How to solve ERROR : package installs executables without proper RPATH

Tags: buildroot

I have this error which is not directly referenced anywere but has a simple solution.

**Context:**

One custom host library compiled in Buildroot.
One custom host program compiled with Buildroot and uses this very library.

During make, Buildroot complains like this :

> *** ERROR: package host-zic installs executables without proper RPATH:
> ***   /home/aurelien/Project/[...]/BR_dir/host/bin/my_program

how do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by [Nikos C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856199/nikos-c) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367123/1182849). This is a copy/paste of his answer :

> When you link, specify the directory of the library and also use an
> rpath:
>
> ```
> -Wl,-rpath,/absolute/path/to/your/library -L/absolute/path/to/your/library -llibrary
> ```
>
> -L tells the linker where to find your library at link time, and -rpath tells it where to search for the library at runtime.
>
> Note that -L and -rpath need the directory that contains your .so
> file, not the actual path of the library file itself.

To translate in buildroot language :

```
-Wl,-rpath,$(HOST_DIR)/lib -L$(HOST_DIR)/lib -llibrary
```