# ERROR : package installs executables without proper RPATH - Buildroot

Tags: python, package, buildroot

I'm new to buildroot. I used the scanpypi script to add external packages to Buildroot. When I run the compilation (`make` command), I quickly have this error returned :

```
>>> host-mkpasswd  Installing to host directory
/usr/bin/install -D -m 755 /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/build/host-mkpasswd/mkpasswd /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/mkpasswd
***
*** ERROR: package host-mkpasswd installs executables without proper RPATH:
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/openssl
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/fdtoverlay
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/genimage
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/setfacl
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/getfacl
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/pkgconf
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/attr
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/fdtget
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/chacl
***   /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/host/bin/fdtput
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:262: /home/ouriacc/Desktop/workspace/BUILDROOT/buildroot-2021.05-rc2_config/output/build/host-mkpasswd/.stamp_host_installed] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

I search for an answer on the forums but all I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369563/how-to-solve-error-package-installs-executables-without-proper-rpath) which I can't understand... Can someone be more explicit about what I should do to remove it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some tries, I fixed the issue by running : `make clean world`.